# Find the first value in the binary tree

Tags: java, c++

where each node has a pointer to a sibling and a child.

Say that every node is either True or False, and you want to find the first node that is True (first means the shallowest).

How would you solve this?  You are given the node to the head of the tree

can solve in java/c++.

Comment: Stop cheating. Stop being lazy. Do your own homework.


Comment: Do you have anything that you've tried so far?

Comment: And you, how would you solve it ? We are pleased to help you if you show a minimum of efforts..

Comment: I'm just gonna leave this here. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search

Comment: Trees have branches and those branches have branches.  ie multiple children. Branches do not join each other. Ie they don't connect to siblings.

Answer (score 2):

As a hint, if you want to find the shallowest node in a tree with some property, you can use breadth-first search starting from the root.

The tree representation shouldn't be too much of an issue here, since when doing a BFS you would want to insert all of a node's children into the queue. The only difference between the normal representation and this representation is how you find the children.

I'll leave all the details to you, including doing the research to learn what these basic terms and definitions are, as an exercise. Your question is clearly some form of assignment or interview question and it would be terribly dishonest of me to just give you code.

Hope this helps!